# Expanding ansible yaml jinja template without running ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

Is it possible to format a yaml in jinja2 template file like this:

```yaml
foo:
  - "A"
  - "B"

bar: 
  inner2: "{{ foo }}"

baz:
  bla:
    inner1: "{{bar.inner2 | sort | join | lower}}"
```

back to proper yaml like this:

```yaml
foo:
  - "A"
  - "B"

bar: 
  inner2:
    - "A"
    - "B"

baz:
  bla:
    inner1: "ab"
```

is there any command line (not ansible) that can generate back to proper yaml?

```bash
expand-jinja ansible/roles/X/default/main.yml > out.yml
```

Comment: I don't think so since the template will often include fields relative to the target. You could however always run it as a local action and look at the result.

Comment: There is a [`jinja-cli`](https://pypi.org/project/jinja-cli/) library you can use, if that is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Given your above example file saved as `some_vars.yml` you can easilly acheive the expected result with the following `transform.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:
    - some_vars.yml

  tasks:
    - template:
        src: some_vars.yml
        dest: some_vars_expanded.yml
```

which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook transform.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [template] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Checking the result file with `cat some_vars_expanded.yml`

```yaml
foo:
  - "A"
  - "B"

bar: 
  inner2: "['A', 'B']"

baz:
  bla:
    inner1: "ab"
```